# DNS for kubernetes pods and airflow worker logs

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-dns

```sh
➜ k get pods -n edna    
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
airflow-79d5f59644-dd4k7          1/1     Running   0          16h
airflow-worker-67bcf7844b-rq7r8   1/1     Running   0          22h
backend-65bcb6546-wvvqj           1/1     Running   0          2d16h
```

so airflow running in **airflow-79d5f59644-dd4k7** pod is trying to get logs extracted from the airflow worker (celery/python, which runs a simple flask based webserver handling logs) and it can't because domain name **airflow-worker-67bcf7844b-rq7r8** is not resolved inside **airflow-79d5f59644-dd4k7**

```
*** Log file does not exist: /usr/local/airflow/logs/hello_world/hello_task/2020-07-14T22:05:12.123747+00:00/1.log
*** Fetching from: http://airflow-worker-67bcf7844b-rq7r8:8793/log/hello_world/hello_task/2020-07-14T22:05:12.123747+00:00/1.log
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. HTTPConnectionPool(host='airflow-worker-67bcf7844b-rq7r8', port=8793): Max retries exceeded with url: /log/hello_world/hello_task/2020-07-14T22:05:12.123747+00:00/1.log (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd37d6a9790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```

How can I make this work?

I understand that Airflow has remote logging to s3, but Is there a way to route requests by POD random hasotnames?

I have created a NodeType Service, but airflow has NO idea about DNS name for that service and is trying to access logs by hostname of the airflow worker (reported back by Celery).

```
➜ k get pods -n edna
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
airflow-79d5f59644-dd4k7          1/1     Running   0          16h
airflow-worker-67bcf7844b-rq7r8   1/1     Running   0          22h
backend-65bcb6546-wvvqj           1/1     Running   0          2d17h

kubectl get pods -n edna -l app=edna-airflow-worker \                                                                        
    -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{.status.podIP}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'
'Tipz:' kgp -n edna -l app=edna-airflow-worker \ -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{.status.podIP}}{{" "}}{{end}}'
10.0.101.120
```

Get inside the **airflow-79d5f59644-dd4k7** pod

```
k exec -ti -n edna airflow-79d5f59644-dd4k7 bash  

  [DEV] airflow-79d5f59644-dd4k7 app # curl -L http://airflow-worker-67bcf7844b-rq7r8:8793/log/hello_world/hello_task/2020-07-14T21:59:01.400678+00:00/1.log

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: airflow-worker-67bcf7844b-rq7r8; Unknown error
  [DEV] airflow-79d5f59644-dd4k7 app # curl -L http://10.0.101.120:8793/log/hello_world/hello_task/2020-07-14T21:59:01.400678+00:00/1.log
[2020-07-14 21:59:07,257] {{taskinstance.py:669}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: hello_world.hello_task 2020-07-14T21:59:01.400678+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-07-14 21:59:07,341] {{taskinstance.py:669}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: hello_world.hello_task 2020-07-14T21:59:01.400678+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-07-14 21:59:07,342] {{taskinstance.py:879}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-07-14 21:59:07,342] {{taskinstance.py:880}} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2020-07-14 21:59:07,342] {{taskinstance.py:881}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-07-14 21:59:07,348] {{taskinstance.py:900}} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): hello_task> on 2020-07-14T21:59:01.400678+00:00
[2020-07-14 21:59:07,351] {{standard_task_runner.py:53}} INFO - Started process 5795 to run task
[2020-07-14 21:59:07,912] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: hello_world.hello_task 2020-07-14T21:59:01.400678+00:00 [running]> airflow-worker-67bcf7844b-rq7r8
[2020-07-14 21:59:07,989] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - Hello world! This is really cool!
[2020-07-14 21:59:07,989] {{python_operator.py:114}} INFO - Done. Returned value was: Hello world! This is really cool!
[2020-07-14 21:59:08,161] {{taskinstance.py:1065}} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS.dag_id=hello_world, task_id=hello_task, execution_date=20200714T215901, start_date=20200714T215907, end_date=20200714T215908
[2020-07-14 21:59:17,070] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2020-07-14 21:59:17,070] {{local_task_job.py:103}} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
  [DEV] airflow-79d5f59644-dd4k7 app #
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution**

Provide the following ENV **AIRFLOW__CORE__HOSTNAME_CALLABLE** for the deployment.yaml of the worker pod:

```
env:
  - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__HOSTNAME_CALLABLE
    value: 'airflow.utils.net:get_host_ip_address'
```

Or just change airflow.cfg

then airflow is trying to access by IP of the POD and things are working if your POD exposes port **8793**

Comment: This also solved my `*** Could not read served logs: [Errno -2] Name or service not known` in Airflow 2.6.0!

Answer (score 1):

> If a **pod A** wants to communicate to **pod B**, pod B has to be exposed with a service **svc-b**.
>
> Then pod A can communicate with the svc-b.

This is the rule.

For your case, pod B is airflow-worker-67bcf7844b-rq7r8 :

```
kubectl -n edna expose airflow-worker-67bcf7844b-rq7r8 \
  --name airflow-worker \
  --port 8793 \
  --target-port 8793
```

Now feel free to use `curl -L http://airflow-worker:8793/` instead of `curl -L http://airflow-worker-67bcf7844b-rq7r8:8793/`

Comment: I did this, but airflow has no idea that such service (and DNS name) exists. And tried to access by hostname of the POD which is reported by celery.

Comment: What does the following command show `kubectl  -n edna exec -it airflow-worker-67bcf7844b-rq7r8 -- curl -L http://localhost:8793/log/hello_world/hello_task/2020-07-14T21:59:01.400678+00:00/1.log `    ? Please copy/paste it as it is.

Comment: The output of the command 
https://gist.github.com/githubsaritasa/18ac363fb584aeb2748ee39116962a9b

Comment: I am running inot the same issue as @DmitrySemenov